# Neotree open file in split window

Tags: package, window, frames

Is there a way to open a file from Neotree in a new split window?

I want to achive same functionality as Vim NERDTree shortcuts "i" and "s"

Or is that the wrong approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### New recommendation (Jan 2017)

[`neotree`](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) comes with default bindings of `|` for vertical split and `-` for horizontal split.

*The functions `neotree-enter-horizontal-split` and `neotree-enter-vertical-split` mentioned in my older recommendation below do not exist any more!*

---

### Old recommendation (May 2015)

Currently the `i` and `I` keys are not bound in `neotree-mode-map`.

So you can use the below after `(require 'neotree)`,

```el
(define-key neotree-mode-map (kbd "i") #'neotree-enter-horizontal-split)
(define-key neotree-mode-map (kbd "I") #'neotree-enter-vertical-split)
```

Then, when the cursor is on a file name, pressing `i` will open that file in a new window after horizontal split.

Comment: Does this depend on evil mode or spacemacs? I don't have either, and I tried the above answer and it produces `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument commandp neotree-enter-horizontal-split)  call-interactively(neotree-enter-horizontal-split nil nil)  command-execute(neotree-enter-horizontal-split)`

Comment: @mark Please have a look at the update answer. Thanks for bringing this to my notice.

Comment: @KaushalModi Thanks. Ah, my issue was complicated by the fact that `el-get` was installing an outdated version of `neotree` (described here https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/219 ). Now that I'm using the latest version of neotree, `-` and `|` are working as expected

Answer (score 2):

In case of evil mode, you can do like this

```
(add-hook 'neotree-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (define-key evil-normal-state-local-map (kbd "TAB") 'neotree-enter-vertical-split)
        (define-key evil-normal-state-local-map (kbd "SPC") 'neotree-enter-horizontal-split)
        (define-key evil-normal-state-local-map (kbd "q") 'neotree-hide)
        (define-key evil-normal-state-local-map (kbd "RET") 'neotree-enter)))
```

Comment: I need this to actually use neotree